# VBA to show/hide data in Word

Tags: vba, checkbox, bookmarks

I am writing a huge procedural manual and would love to be able to hide/show sections as needed. I found the correct way to do it, through bookmarks, check boxes and VBA but am unable to get all three to come together.

These are the instructions I am using:
[Link to Instruction Sets](https://itstillworks.com/problems-letters-disappearing-microsoft-word-12036433.html)

They seem simple enough but I am unable to "view code" by right clicking on the checkbox. Is this a necessary step to add the code or can I just open a new macro and insert the code there?

Other ideas to achieve hiding/showing sections with bookmarks are welcome, too. Thank you!

Comment: You could try double-clicking the checkbox.  This will also create the event and take you to the code window.

Comment: "These are the instructions I am using" where?

Comment: Forgot the link :)

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://itstillworks.com/problems-letters-disappearing-microsoft-word-12036433.html&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1592923597249000&usg=AFQjCNHMz8uh06JZmoHHQSeFtWAZHoIsoA